# How to solve $\int_0^\infty \left(\sqrt{1-\gamma(t)}e^{c\gamma(t)}-1\right)dt$, where $\gamma(t) = \frac{e^{-at}}{b+e^{-at}}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

$$\int_0^\infty \left(\sqrt{1-\gamma(t)}e^{c\gamma(t)}-1\right)dt,$$
where
$$\gamma(t) = \frac{e^{-at}}{b+e^{-at}}.$$

I'll be glad if anyone can help me with this. I already tried some obvious substitutions, unsuccessfully of course. I rather have an exact result, however, if this can only be solved approximatively I would ideally have an expansion in $b$.

Comment: Wanted: a better title of your question. (Don't get me wrong, it's fine to put in a joke. But not at the expense of being suboptimal. In this case, you can definitely put the integral itself in the title.)

Comment: Also, accepting an answer awards 15 points, but you can only do it for one person. What if two people post a solution?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I had actually upvoted just because of the humour. =)

Comment: @Sobi: That is a *terrible* reason to upvote a question or an answer. At best, it's a reasonable reason to vote a comment.

Comment: @Parcly: All $\rm\LaTeX$ titles make it impossible to right-click on the link, and generally one should prefer *some* text in a title. Just for future reference.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I included parentheses outside $ against that scenario.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Fair enough!

Comment: @Parcly: Yes. Leaving a small sliver of text, in an otherwise unclear title (yes, that's an integral, what seems to be the *actual* question about it?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $b$ is small, I want the leading term.
Let $v=\exp(-at)/b$ to get

$$ \frac 1a\int_0^{1/b}\left[\sqrt{\frac1{1+v}}\exp(\frac{cv}{1+v})-1\right] \frac{dv}v$$

The function is bounded at $v=0$ and the main term is $O(v^{-3/2})$ for large $v$.  So the dominant part of the integral is $ \int \frac{-1}v dv$ for large $v$ near $v=1/b$, and that gives $\log b$.

So I think the dominant term is $(\log b)/a$

The next term would be $f(c)/a$ where 
$$f(c)/a=\frac1a\int_0^1[g(c,v)-1]\frac{dv}v+\frac1a\int_1^\infty g(c,v)\frac{dv}v$$
and after that a correction term
$$\frac1a\int_{1/b}^\infty g(c,v)\frac{dv}v$$
which is roughly $2\sqrt{b}\exp(c)/a$

Comment: Since the integral probably does not have an exact solution I decided to accept your answer. Thanks for your work!